# Any viable alternatives to merge function? R and R Studio shut down

Tags: r, merge

I'm trying to merge to data frames based on a common field called "lookup" that I created. I created the data frames after subsetting the original data frame.
Each of the two newly created data frames is less than 10,000 rows. When trying to execute merge, after much thinking, both R and R Studio shuts down, with R sometimes producing an error message stating:

Error in make.unique(as.character(rows)) : 
  promise already under evaluation: recursive default argument reference or earlier problems?

Below is my code...is there any other way to pull down the data from the other data frame based on the common field besides using the merge function? Any help is appreciated.

Also, do you have any thoughts as to why it may be shutting down, using up all the memory, when, in fact, the data size is so small?

```
  wmtdata <- datastep2[datastep2$Market.Type=="WMT", c("Item", "Brand.Family", "Brand", "Unit.Size", "Pack.Size", 
                                                     "Container", "UPC..int.", "X..Vol", "Unit.Vol", "Distribution", "Market.Type",
                                                     "Week.Ending", "MLK.Day","Easter", "Independence.Day", "Labor.Day", "Veterans.Day", "Thanksgiving",
                                                     "Christmas", "New.Years","Year","Month","Week.Sequence","Price")]

compdata <- datastep2[datastep2$Market.Type=="Rem Mkt", c("Week.Ending", "UPC..int.","X..Vol", "Unit.Vol", "Price","lookup")]

colnames(compdata)[colnames(compdata)=="X..Vol"]<-"Comp Vol"
colnames(compdata)[colnames(compdata)=="Unit.Vol"]<-"Comp Unit Vol"
colnames(compdata)[colnames(compdata)=="Price"]<-"Comp Price"


combineddata <-merge(wmtdata, compdata, by="lookup")
```

Comment: Your code must not reflect your actual issue, because the column "lookup" does not exist in both data frames. If that were actually the case your code would immediately stop with an error.

Comment: (Additionally, simply Googling "alternatives to merge in r" would have given you a lot to go on.)

Comment: thanks, Joran. Pardon my omission, the "lookup" column does exist in both data sets, I simply forgot to put it in the above reference.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using data frames, use the **data.table** package ([see here for an intro](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-intro.pdf)).  A data.table is like an indexed data frame.  It has its own merge method that would probably work in this case.

Comment: I agree with the data.table recommendation, but I disagree that 10k rows is a lot. data.table will be faster, but I use merge on data that size routinely with little issues.

Comment: thanks, @ChristopherLouden. My inability to use 'merge' or 'join' on a data frame that size still puzzles me (I have plenty of memory, but during the operation, R eats up all the available memory, making it a 'memory problem'. After 2-3 minutes of working, R and RStudio shuts down. I will give the data table method a go.

Comment: How much memory do you have?  I would check out [Hadley Wickham's chapter](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/memory.html) on memory usage to get a better understanding of how R handles memory.

Comment: @joran: I shouldn't make such statements with out more data or explanation to back it up.  It is withdrawn.

Answer (score 1):

Try `join` from the `plyr` package:

```
combineddata <- join(wmtdata, compdata, by="lookup")
```

Comment: Thanks, @amzu. Viable method, but still the operation would not complete due to timeouts, even though it is structurally sound.

Answer (score 1):

With only 10,000 rows, the problem is unlikely to be the use of `merge(...)` instead of something else. Are the elements of the `lookup` column unique? Otherwise you get a cross-join.

Consider this trivial case:

```
df.1 <- data.frame(id=rep(1,10), x=rnorm(10))
df.2 <- data.frame(id=rep(1,10), y=rnorm(10))
z <- merge(df.1,df.2,by="id")
nrow(z)
# [1] 100
```

So two `df` with 10 rows each produce a merge with 100 rows because the id is not unique.

Now consider:

```
df.1 <- data.frame(id=rep(1:10, each=40), x=rnorm(400))
df.2 <- data.frame(id=rep(1:10, each=50), y=rnorm(500))
z <- merge(df.1,df.2,by="id")
nrow(z)
# [1] 20000
```

In this example, `df.1` has each id replicated 40 times, and in `df.2` each id is replicated 50 times. Merge will produce one row *for every instance of an id in each df*, so 50 X 40 =2000 rows *per id*. Since there are 10 ids in this example, you get 20,000 rows. So your merge results can get very big very quickly if the id field (`lookup` in your case) is not unique.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you all for all the great help. Data tables are the way to go for me, as I think this was a memory issue ("lookup" values were common between data frames). While 8 GB of memory (~ 6GB free) should be plenty, it was all used up during this process. nevertheless, data tables worked just fine. Learning a lot from these boards.